# CSS bootstrap : How offset works in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i am not css developer but i am trying to lean bootstrap usage. so i was reading article from this url http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/overview-of-bootstrap-buttons-and-grid-offset/

i am curious to know how bootstrap offset works?

see some code example

1)

```
<div class="container">  
    <div class="row">  
        <div class="col-md-3col-md-offset-3 ">  
            <div class="customDiv">column 1</div>  
        </div>  
        <div class="col-md-3">  
            <div class="customDiv">column 2</div>  
        </div>  
</div>
```

how col-md-offset-3 push two column at center. see the screen shot.
[image]

2) see this one

```
<div class="container">  
    <div class="row">  
        <div class="col-md-3">  
            <div class="customDiv">column 1</div>  
        </div>  
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-6 ">  
            <div class="customDiv">column 2</div>  
        </div>  
    </div>  
</div>
```

how this offset col-md-offset-6 can push two column to corner. one to left and another to right. see the screen shot [image]

3) how image comes at center see the code and screen shot

```
<div class="container">  
    <div class="row"> <img src="one.png" class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 img-responsive" /> </div>  
</div>
```

please explain my each points and tell me how offset works in bootstrap. thanks
[image]

Comment: Bootstrap provides a 12 column grid where each column has a percentage width. "col-md-offset-\*" pushes the element to the right by increasing the left-margin according to the number defined by "\*". See here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting

Comment: Check the Bootstrap 4 Documentation on offset here: [Bootstrap 4 offset](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns)

Comment: for quick idea see: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp. there are 12 blocks, when you say col-md-3 it means use 3 blocks for one div/column. when you say col-md-offset-3 it means leave space equivalent to 3 blocks